# PHP-MySql: Adding Friend

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with following Tables:

- Users table: consisting of ID(int) and Username(varchar)
- Friends table: consisting ID(int) and Friends_ID(varchar)

I tested my script on my localhost and it worked fine but as soon as I uploaded the script to my free webhost of choice, it didn't work correctly. For example a *FriendID* gets added to the *Friendlist* of all users instead of only the specified one.

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
$servername= "********";
$serverusername="********";
$password="**********";
$dbName= "***********";

//Make Connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $serverusername,$password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$connection){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$friend_username = 'Steven';//$_POST["friendusernamePost"]; 
$username ='Hans'; //$_POST["usernamePost"]

$getOwnID_q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' ";
$getFriendID_q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username = '$friend_username' ";

$ownID_result = mysqli_query($connection, $getOwnID_q);
$ownID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ownID_result)["ID"];

$friendID_result = mysqli_query($connection, $getFriendID_q);
$friendID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friendID_result)["ID"];

if($ownID<1)
    echo "ERROR: couldn't get correct Own ID";
else if($friendID<1)
    echo "ERROR: couldn't get correct friend ID";
else{
    $getFriendlist_q= "SELECT Friends_ID From Friends WHERE ID = '$ownID' ";
    $oldFriendlist_result = mysqli_query($connection, $getFriendlist_q);
    $oldFriendlist = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oldFriendlist_result)["Friends_ID"];
    //check if user isnt already friends with other user
    $splitted = explode(";", $oldFriendlist);


    if(in_array($friendID, $splitted)){
        echo "You are already Friends."; 
    }
    else{
        //append ';' at the end of friendID
        $friendID .= ';' ; 
        $updatedFriendlist = $oldFriendlist . $friendID;
        $addID_query = "UPDATE Friends SET Friends_ID = $updatedFriendlist WHERE ID = $ownID ";

        if ($connection->query($addID_query) === TRUE) {
            echo "Friendlist updated successfully";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error updating Friendlist: " . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    $connection->close();
}

?>
```

I have no experience with PHP or MySQL prior to this so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> first you have  a  big problems to concatenate a SQL request with
>   variable

```
$getOwnID_q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' ";
```

> Became

```
$getOwnID_q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username like ' ".$username." ' ";
```

---

```
$getFriendID_q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username = '$friend_username' ";
```

> Became

```
$getFriendID_q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username like ' ".$friend_username." ' ";
```

---

```
$getFriendlist_q= "SELECT Friends_ID From Friends WHERE ID = '$ownID' ";
```

> Became

```
$getFriendlist_q= "SELECT Friends_ID From Friends WHERE ID =".$ownID;
```

---

```
$addID_query = "UPDATE Friends SET Friends_ID = $updatedFriendlist WHERE ID = $ownID ";
```

> Became

```
$addID_query = "UPDATE Friends SET Friends_ID = ".$updatedFriendlist." WHERE ID = ".$ownID;
```